# I am migrating the arcgis js code to 4.24,facing issue in displaying the Polyline geometry json response as graphic on graphicslayer

Tags: json, graphics, arcgis, polyline, arcgis-js-api

I got the Json response from esriRequest and I wanted to display the polyline in wkid:32643 spatial reference.The Json has no type mentioning polyline.
can anyone help me sort this issue?

```
if ((params.flowElements == 'esriFEEdges') || (params.flowElements == 'esriFEJunctionsAndEdges')) {
                    if (result.edges) {
                        var resultFeatures = result.edges;
                        for (var j = 0, jl = resultFeatures.length; j < jl; j++) {
                            var featureSet = resultFeatures[j].features;
                            for (var i = 0, il = featureSet.length; i < il; i++) {
                                var graphic = new esri.Graphic(featureSet[i]);

                                graphicsLayerTraceNetworkEdges.add(graphic);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

/*I need a solution to crack this code*/

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. What is `result`?, the response to what?, can you add an example of the json to the question?.